# Tensorflow gradient through while_loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I've got a tensorflow model where the output of a layer is a 2d tensor, say `t = [[1,2], [3,4]]`.

The next layer expects an input which consists of every row combination of this tensor. That is, I need to turn it into `t_new = [[1,2,1,2], [1,2,3,4], [3,4,1,2], [3,4,3,4]]`.

So far I have tried:

1) `tf.unstack(t, axis=0)` loop over it's rows and append each combination to a buffer, then `t_new = tf.stack(buffer, axis=0)`. This works *except* when the shape is unspecified, ie. None so...

2) I have used a tf.while_loop to generate indices `idx=[[0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]]`, then `t_new = tf.gather(t, idx)`.
My question here is: should I set `back_prop` to `True` or `False` in this `tf.while_loop`? I'm only generating indices inside the loop. Not sure what `back_prop` would even mean.

Also, do you know of a better way to achieve what I need?

Here is the while_loop:

```
i = tf.constant(0)
j = tf.constant(0)
idx = tf.Variable([], dtype=tf.int32)
def body(i, j, idx):
    c = tf.concat([idx, [i, j]], axis=0)
    i, j = tf.cond(tf.equal(j, sentence_len - 1),
                   lambda: (i + 1, 0),
                   lambda: (i, j + 1))
    return i, j, c
_, _, indices = tf.while_loop(lambda i, j, _: tf.less(i, sentence_len),
                             body,
                             [i, j, idx],
                             shape_invariants=[i.get_shape(),
                                               j.get_shape(),
                                               tf.TensorShape([None])])
```

Now I can do `t_new = tf.gather(t, indices)`.

But I am very confused about the meaning of `tf.while_loop`'s `back_prop` - in general and especially here.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you are fine to have `back_prop` as false. It doesn't need to back propagate through the computation of the indices because that computation doesn't depend on any learned variables.

Comment: Even if t is the output of an actual layer, computed using a differentiable function?

Comment: Youre not stopping the backpropagation through t. You're only stopping it through the part of the graph defined in the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context. If you are indexing over some features that are produced from a differentiable function then you want to backpropagate. However, if you are indexing over some input placeholder or input data of some type then you can keep it as false, just as @Aaron said.

Comment: What about when using tf.unstack?Are the gradients propagated properly?

Comment: Yes, using tf.unstack and tf.stack is always tracked by tf.

Comment: Oh ok. In my situation however, it might still be safe to unset back_track in the while loop. I'm thinking tf.gather(t, indices) should take care of it, what do you think?